# Start an app on boot up on an iPad which has been jailbroken. (iOS)

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

Is it possible to start an app on boot up on an iPad which has been jailbroken.

I have managed to use the app Activator to start an app, but only works when the power cable is in.

Answer (score 4):

Install ssh on your jailbroken iPad (through Cydia), then ssh in and write a boot script.

Next write a [`launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) style plist config file and add the file to /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Finally, load the file using [`launchctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html)`load /Library/LaunchDaemons/myplistFile.plist`

This hinges on having launchd on your iPad, which I'm pretty sure is part of the boot sequence on iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but can you give detailed instructions on how to do this. As I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Is the syntax in this thread correct to open my app, only difference would be the name of the app.

Also is there any specifics on name of the .plist file, or can it be what you chose.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882910/using-launchd-on-ios-to-restart-app

Comment: I don't believe the name of the .plist matters but the syntax is pretty specific. Basically what this is doing is registering your app as a startup app with one of the various programs that runs when the iPad boots up.